# center align a section

Tags: html, css

I have a contact section at the bottom of the page that features the location, phone and email of a business. Its set to float to the left however I wish to centre align the whole thing. Ive tried various things but I cant seem to get it to work.

http://pmg.dekastudiotest.net.au/index.html

```css
/* CONTACT */
.contact{ width:100%; float:left; background:#003D98; }
.contact h2{ font-size:0;}
.contact figure{ float:left; margin-right:20px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.contact dl{ display:block;}
.contact dl dt{ font-size:18px; font-weight:700; color:#fff; margin-bottom:10px;}
.contact dl dd{ color:#fff; font-weight:500;}
.contact .container{ padding-bottom:80px; padding-top:100px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);}
```

```html
<section class="contact" style="margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:center;">
  <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 -->
     
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon5.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>LOCATION</dt>
          <dd>Australia Wide Locations</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon6.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>PHONE</dt>
          <dd>+03 8761 4800 - National Reception</dd>

        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <figure><img src="images/icon7.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>E-MAIL</dt>
          <dd>healthcare@pmg.com.au</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
     
      <!-- end col-3 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to keep all three as "col-md-3". Maybe you could change it to something like this:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 -->

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <figure><img src="images/icon5.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>LOCATION</dt>
          <dd>Australia Wide Locations</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure><img src="images/icon6.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>PHONE</dt>
          <dd>+03 8761 4800 - National Reception</dd>

        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-4 -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <figure><img src="images/icon7.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>E-MAIL</dt>
          <dd>healthcare@pmg.com.au</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->

      <!-- end col-3 --> 
    </div>
```

PS: I just added an offset to first col-md-3, and changed second one to col-md-4. If that's what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
#myDivCentered{
     position:absolute;/* or absolute */
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `div` structure like this-

```
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

```css
/* CONTACT */
.contact{ width:100%; float:left; background:#003D98; }
.contact h2{ font-size:0;}
.contact figure{ float:left; margin-right:20px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.contact dl{ display:block;}
.contact dl dt{ font-size:18px; font-weight:700; color:#fff; margin-bottom:10px;}
.contact dl dd{ color:#fff; font-weight:500;}
.contact .container{ padding-bottom:80px; padding-top:100px; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.4);}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="contact" style="margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   display:center;">
  <div class="container wow fadeInUp">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-12 -->
     
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <figure><img src="images/icon5.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>LOCATION</dt>
          <dd>Australia Wide Locations</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure><img src="images/icon6.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>PHONE</dt>
          <dd>+03 8761 4800 - National Reception</dd>

        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <figure><img src="images/icon7.png" alt="Image"></figure>
        <dl>
          <dt>E-MAIL</dt>
          <dd>healthcare@pmg.com.au</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
      <!-- end col-3 -->
     
      <!-- end col-3 --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end row --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</section>
```

[image]

I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="contact">
<div class="container wow fadeInUp">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-12">
<h2>CONTACT</h2>
</div>
<!-- end col-12 -->

<div class="col-md-4">
<figure><img src="images/icon5.png" alt="Image"></figure>
<dl>
<dt>LOCATION</dt>
<dd>Australia Wide Locations</dd>
</dl>
</div>

<!-- end col-3 -->
<div class="col-md-4">
<figure><img src="images/icon6.png" alt="Image"></figure>
<dl>
<dt>PHONE</dt>
<dd>+03 8761 4800 - National Reception</dd>

</dl>
</div>

<!-- end col-3 -->
<div class="col-md-4">
<figure><img src="images/icon7.png" alt="Image"></figure>
<dl>
<dt>E-MAIL</dt>
<dd>healthcare@pmg.com.au</dd>
</dl>
</div>

<!-- end col-3 --> 
</div>  
<!-- end row --> 
</div>
<!-- end container --> 
</section>
```

i have not done any modification in your css. just modified the col-md in the  section changed to col-m's to col-md-3. please feel free to ask if any clarification.